# Como crear esta Base de datos Mysql

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

No tengo idea de MySQL y tengo una imagen de lo que necesito, me gustaría un ayuda o algún tutorial para seguir.

Lo que estoy haciendo es llamando desde `Xcode` imágenes ubicadas en un servidor, pero este tipo de organización es la que necesito, mas exactamente como ingresar esa `URL` en ese campo, que clase de campo debe ser `INT`, `VARCHAR` o cual de todos. 
Mil gracias.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Debes postear lo que has intentado, si vienes aqui pidiendole a la gente que haga las cosas por ti no va funcionar, tienes que poner preguntas especificas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parece que el campo "*id*" es un `int` y "*name*" es un `text` o un `varchar` (cuyo tamaño dependerá del tamaño máximo que quieras dejar para la URL).

Por ejemplo, podrías crear una tabla similar haciendo `id` clave primaria y con auto-incremento, y limitando `name` a un máximo de 255 caracteres, y el código sería como éste:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `images` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```